# Quick Question- is This valid?,

Tags: probability

quick question I was looking to find the intersection of $3$ events $A,B$ and $C$( I couldn't find anything online to affirm this)

just wanted to know is $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ the same as $P(A\cup B)\times P(B\cup C)$

thanks!

Comment: how can you say it's impossible, without any given information on the question? why is B u C impossible

Comment: You changed the question after my comment.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not true. Consider the following counter-example. Let $A=B=C$ and let's say $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac{1}{3}$. Then $A \cup B \cup C = A$ as well as $B \cup C = A$ and $B \cup C = A$ but $$ P(A \cup B \cup C) = \frac{1}{3} \neq \frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = P(A\cup B) \cdot P(B\cup C).$$

Comment: Since you have to prove this for probabilities, assume values $\le1$. For example, $1/3,1/4,1/5$ etc. are fine.

Comment: Yes I see, I edited it @ShubhamJohri